# Google Play Games Services Alert: "Detected incorrect implementation"

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I recently received the following alert for my game in the Google Play Developer Console:

> Detected incorrect implementation
>
> Your game has incorrectly implemented the following Play Games services: Achievements.

It provides a link to [a help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3433208#games_alerts) but the page only provides the following information:

> Detected incorrect implementation
>
> This game has implemented invitations but doesn't allow users to join a match from an invitation. This approach is discouraged because it could result in a poor user experience.

This does not help me because it mentions invitations (which my app does not use) instead of achievements.

I find it strange that I am getting the error now as I published the last update in May. I am also able to earn achievements when using the app myself, so the fact that I get this message bugs me.

Can you answer these questions:

1. Are these alerts ever erroneous? Is it possible my app is fine after all, or is there definitely something I did wrong?
2. If there is something wrong with my app, how do I go about fixing this? What are common sources of error that cause this message?
3. Is this message supposed to be a friendly reminder that I am doing something wrong or is it a warning that they will remove my app/terminate my account if I don't do something about it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I got it today too in multiple games. It's either a new validation rule or a bug in Google Play (I noticed before weird warnings that just went away).

Comment: can you share your package name or app id that is having this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google had updated the information about the "Detected incorrect implementation".Please check the your "a help page".

> Achievements: This game has created achievements in the Developer Console, but never calls the SDK's unlock methods. This approach is discouraged because it could result in a poor user experience.

I also encountered this warning and check the app really do not follow the [checklist](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist#2_achievements) of google play services about achievements.Please re-check your app whether it follows the ***Required*** rows in the [checklist](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist#2_achievements).

I have already uploaded my modified app to google play.When the warning disappears, I will share the information with you.

Comment: This makes sense. There are a couple of achievements that none of my users have unlocked yet, since I don't have many downloads.

Comment: New Update: It's about 5 days,after I had re-uploaded my modified app.The warning is gone.So make sure you really call the method such as "UnlockAchievement".

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of this alert is when you call [unlock](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements.html#unlock(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String)) or [increment](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements.html#increment(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) and pass an invalid `id` as per the [games alert descriptions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3433208#games_alerts). Double check that the `id`s listed in the developer console match the ids listed in your game - preferably, use the 'Get resources' option in the Developer Console to get an XML file that you can be sure matches Google Play Games exactly.

Comment: Note: in this particular case, it very much seems to be an automated system error that went haywire - I too have a game that is showing an alert but everything matches so if you don't find anything wrong this specific time I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I checked to make sure the IDs in my resource file matched; they do, as I expected. I'm going to give this some time to see if it is an error on Google's part. I don't want to be trying to fix a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Same for me. Achievements are implemented and are working for months without problem. 
All my ids are in a file exported from the Developer console, so I'm 100% sure there is no mistake in this list.
As said before, may be a bug

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting these messages, even for apps that dont have any integration with GPGS at all (No leaderboards, achievements ... they dont even include the api). Perhaps it's an issue with some kind of automated checking rollout.

Comment: Paul's comment contributes nothing to this discussion, aside from highlighting his arrogant behaviour. I have several published and unpublished apps that this alert has flagged that dont even use GPGS at all, nor do they include any code/libs/api that could possibly relate to this alert. This would lend to the conclusion that it is a bug in an automated process, as hinted at above - Paul needs to learn how to read.

Comment: No offense, but in my humble opinion the answer you provided is much more like a comment rather than an answer, per convention of stackoverflow. I was doing a 'Triage' review for stackoverflow, and I think I need to point that out.