# Google Play Console - "Your game has incorrectly implemented the following Play Games services: Achievements."

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-developers-console

For our Android game that uses Google Play Games Services only for login and that has no achievements set up, we're receiving this Alert in the Google Developer Console: "Your game has incorrectly implemented the following Play Games services: Achievements."

According to this [Documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3433208#games_alerts), this means that we set up an achievement but never unlock it - but we don't have any.

Is there any other possible reason for this Alert to show?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955983/google-play-games-services-alert-detected-incorrect-implementation

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a duplicate and I read it prior to making this post. The answer in this post says to check for achievements being setup correctly if using them - but we are not using achievements.

Comment: Hi, I just received this error today so I may fix it by the time you get back to me. I have my game published, achievements set up and working, but I got this error. Do you have any experience or follow up questions that might help me out?

Comment: It might be because my achievements have duplicate icons, but if you have any other suggestions they are welcome.